# Fetch Data from Realtime Database Firebase in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

I have some data present on **Real time database**. But when I am fetching the data it is giving me error.

I have the data like this on **Realtime database**:

```
"Transaction_By_Date": {
    "Ahmad_24-03-2023 17:38:15": {
      "28-03-2023": {
        "total_amount_receive": 10000,
        "total_amount_send": 20000,
        "transactions": {
          "-NRZfbq2xYhHF-v1beKC": {
            "amount": 20000,
            "date": "28-03-2023 01:06:53",
            "detail": "Sending",
            "image": "no image",
            "type": "Send"
          },
          "-NRZfs_i1RWHQ-8xYYa1": {
            "amount": 10000,
            "date": "28-03-2023 01:07:40",
            "detail": "Detail",
            "image": "no image",
            "type": "Receive"
          }
        },
      "29-03-2023": {
        "total_amount_receive": 5000,
        "total_amount_send": 0,
        "transactions": {
          "-NRZfxRoPkLQxOJfCyGq": {
            "amount": 5000,
            "date": "28-03-2023 01:08:24",
            "detail": "Received",
            "image": "no image",
            "type": "Receive"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I had tried to fetch this response like this using **FirebaseDatabaseSwift**.
My code is:

```
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseDatabaseSwift

func getEntries(userId: String) {

    Database.database().reference().child("Transaction_By_Date").child(userId).observe(.value) { snapshot in
            
        guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
            return
        }
        
        let transactionsData = children.compactMap { dictionary in
            
            do {
                
                var transaction = try dictionary.data(as: TransactionByDate.self)
                transaction.id = dictionary.ref.key
                return transaction
                
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return TransactionByDate()
            }
        }
    
        print(transactionsData)
    }
}
```

This is my **TransactionByDate** model:

```
struct TransactionByDate: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    var id: String?
    var total_amount_sent: Int?
    var total_amount_receive: Int?
    var transactions: [Transactions]?
}

struct Transactions: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    var id: String?
    var amount: Int?
    var date: String?
    var detail: String?
    var image: String?
    var type: String?
}
```

When this function is being called. I am getting this error:

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong. And what can I add up to make it work?

Comment: Change `print(error.localizedDescription)` to `print(error)` and you should get a much more informative and detailed error message.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson getting this error: `typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "transactions", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: Add it to the question instead for better readability. The error message tells you that the property `transactions` is a dictionary and not an array

Answer (score 0):

A Joakim pointed out, the `transactions` node in your JSON is a dictionary, not an array. This is normal when you [create a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) in Firebase by calling `childByAutoId`.

To fix the error, declare your `transactions` property as a dictionary:

```
var transactions: [String: Transactions]?
```

To learn more about why Firebase doesn't use arrays for such lists, I recommend reading [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)..